# unable to select one radio button at a time

Tags: html

I am unable to select one radio button at a time. Multiple buttons are getting selected.  I am newbie to html. This is my code. Please help.

```
<form name="ans_a" onsubmit="return answer_a()">
    <table align="center" border="1">
        <br>
        <br>
        <tr>
            <td width="500px"> ABC 
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="A" value="a" id="radio1"> A &nbsp Option A <br>
                <input type="radio" name="B" value="b" id="radio2"> B &nbsp Option B <br>
                <input type="radio" name="C" value="c" id="radio3"> C &nbsp Option C <br>
                <input type="radio" name="D" value="d" id="radio4"> D &nbsp Option D <br>
                <br>
                &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
                <input type="button" name="ans1" value="Next" onclick="answer_a()">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: give same name to all buttons..

Comment: @Barmar Things that are obvious to you or me won't be to someone brand new. I personally can see how if I'm asked to have different `id` and `value` properties can easily vary the `name` attribute as "Just another attribute."  I could also design a schema whereby the "Grouping" could be handled by the container they were housed in.  Such as, say, with the "option" tag within a "select" tag.  In the future, I'd keep in mind that it takes bits of both desperation and courage to post to a community of experts and that outright criticism will simply dissuade future pursuit and participation in CS.

Comment: yea i saw the tutorials but didn't noticed this small change

Comment: @garromark I'm sorry, but after a while here I get totally fed up with what seems like total cluelessness. I don't really expect her to divine this herself, but whatever book or web site she learned `type="radio"` from must surely have explained this. They just have to read.

Comment: @Barmar I know where you're coming from.  I notice some questions that obviously lack proper background research.  My personal criterion for "caring" about a person's problem when it comes to their experience level is to give more credence to the need of complete beginners over even slightly more experienced, novice developers by considering the fact that computer science is hard and that even the act of understanding documentation is a developed skill that I think we take for granted.  I, for one, read perhaps 5% of a documentation page to find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The name attribute must be the same to select only one radio `button` at a time. The id could be different depending on if you want to capture that somewhere which one of the radio buttons is selected.

```
<input type="radio" name="A" value="a" id="radio1"> A &nbsp Option A <br>
<input type="radio" name="A" value="b" id="radio2"> B &nbsp Option B <br>
<input type="radio" name="A" value="c" id="radio3"> C &nbsp Option C <br>
<input type="radio" name="A" value="d" id="radio4"> D &nbsp Option D <br>
```

Answer (score 3):

To select only one radio button, you have to put them under one group, i.e make the name attribute same for all of them.

```
<input type="radio" name="options" value="a" id="radio1"> A &nbsp Option A <br>
<input type="radio" name="options" value="b" id="radio2"> B &nbsp Option B <br>
<input type="radio" name="options" value="c" id="radio3"> C &nbsp Option C <br>
<input type="radio" name="options" value="d" id="radio4"> D &nbsp Option D <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

try same name for all the radio buttons i used like this in my project

```
 <div class="col-md-2">   <label><input type="radio" class="classone" name="A">Daily</label> </div>
 <div class="col-md-2">   <label><input type="radio" class="classone" name="A">Weekly</label> </div>
 <div class="col-md-2">   <label><input type="radio" class="classone" name="A">Monthly</label> </div>
 <div class="col-md-2">   <label><input type="radio" class="classone" name="A">Yearly</label> </div>
```