# Implementatio of radio button in html table. Issue: All are selecting instead of selecting one

Tags: jquery, html

Hi [Image that shows all the radio buttons are selecting at a time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuarr.jpg)
I implemented radio buttons in the table for every row. I want to select only one row at a time but all the rows are in selected when clicking on them instead of selecting only one and deselecting other one. 
Here is the code.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="50"></th>
            <th>Device ID <span class="caret"></span></th>
            <th>Device Name <span class="caret"></span></th>
            <th>Work URL <span class="caret"></span></th>
            <th>MSISDN <span class="caret"></span></th>
            <th width="200">Network <span class="caret"></span></th>
            <th>Region <span class="caret"></span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center"><div class="radio radio-circle"><input type="radio" id="radio99"><label for="radio99"></label></div></th>
            <th><label class="hide" for="deviceID">Device ID</label><input type="text" class="device_col_search" id="deviceID" name="deviceId"></th>
            <th><label class="hide" for="deviceName">Device Name</label><input type="text" class="device_col_search" id="deviceName" name="deviceName"></th>
            <th><label class="hide" for="workurl">all</label><input type="text" class="device_col_search" id="workurl" name="workurl"></th>
            <th><label class="hide" for="msisdn">all</label><input type="text" class="device_col_search" id="msisdn" name="msisdn"></th>
            <th><label class="hide" for="network">all</label><input type="text" class="device_col_search" id="network" name="network"></th>
            <th><label class="hide" for="region">all</label><input type="text" class="device_col_search" id="region" name="region"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="radio radio-circle"><input type="radio" id="radio4"><label for="radio4"></label></div></td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Unknown</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>6822201112</td>
            <td>Jmeter Home Carrier</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="radio radio-circle"><input type="radio" id="radio5"><label for="radio5"></label></div></td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Unknown</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>6822201112</td>
            <td>Jmeter Home Carrier</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="radio radio-circle"><input type="radio" id="radio6"><label for="radio6"></label></div></td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>Unknown</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>6822201112</td>
            <td>Jmeter Home Carrier</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="radio radio-circle"><input type="radio" id="radio7"><label for="radio7"></label></div></td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>Unknown</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>6822201112</td>
            <td>Jmeter Home Carrier</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="radio radio-circle"><input type="radio" id="radio8"><label for="radio8"></label></div></td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>Unknown</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>6822201112</td>
            <td>Jmeter Home Carrier</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="radio radio-circle"><input type="radio" id="radio9"><label for="radio9"></label></div></td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>Unknown</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>6822201112</td>
            <td>Jmeter Home Carrier</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="radio radio-circle"><input type="radio" id="radio10"><label for="radio10"></label></div></td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>Unknown</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>6822201112</td>
            <td>Jmeter Home Carrier</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="radio radio-circle"><input type="radio" id="radio11"><label for="radio11"></label></div></td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>Unknown</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>6822201112</td>
            <td>Jmeter Home Carrier</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="radio radio-circle"><input type="radio" id="radio12"><label for="radio12"></label></div></td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>Unknown</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>6822201112</td>
            <td>Jmeter Home Carrier</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="radio radio-circle"><input type="radio" id="radio13"><label for="radio13"></label></div></td>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>Unknown</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>6822201112</td>
            <td>Jmeter Home Carrier</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="radio radio-circle"><input type="radio" id="radio14"><label for="radio14"></label></div></td>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>Unknown</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>6822201112</td>
            <td>Jmeter Home Carrier</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="radio radio-circle"><input type="radio" id="radio15"><label for="radio15"></label></div></td>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>Unknown</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>6822201112</td>
            <td>Jmeter Home Carrier</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuarr.jpg
```

Comment: you mean you only want `one` item to be selected?

Comment: You need to give same name for all radio input. http://jsfiddle.net/q2mzvtuo/

Comment: Use name="" all same name like <input name="form" type="radio" id="radio5">

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to select one radio button at a time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799533/unable-to-select-one-radio-button-at-a-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to put a common name on the `radio buttons` you want to group.

Like :

```
<input type="radio" id="radio4" name="radio" />
<input type="radio" id="radio5" name="radio" />
<input type="radio" id="radio6" name="radio" />
....
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add name in radio button 
as :

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1"/>
```

after this you can add a label or value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the common name for the radio button and name is the attribute.

```
<input type="radio" id="radio5" value="5" name="5">5
<input type="radio" id="radio6" value="6" name="5">6
<input type="radio" id="radio7" value="7" name="5">7
```